# Import from a subdirectory of a sibling folder

Tags: python

I have a structure like this:

```
project_dir/
    a/
        b/
            to_import.py
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
    c/
        main.py
        __init__.py
```

I need to import `to_import.py` from `main.py`. In `main.py` I write

```
from ..a.b.to_import import something
```

I have an error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
I put `__init__.py` everywhere because I saw an advice to do it. Also, I do it in PyCharm

Comment: You're probably best to ensure that the parent of `project_dir` is in `sys.path` and then use an absolute import (`from project_dir.a.b.to_import import something`).

Comment: @alani I tried to add project_dir in sys.path using `sys.path.append('..')`, then used `from project_dir.a.b.to_import import something`. I have the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_dir'`

Comment: I've added an answer to give more detail on how you can put it into the `sys.path`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an absolute import:

```
from project_dir.a.b.to_import import something
```

If the parent directory of `project_dir` is not in your `sys.path` and it is not convenient to set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to ensure this before calling python, then you could force it by putting the following into your `main.py` before the `import` statement shown above:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../.."))
```